# VME64 vs PCI Bus for vibrating environment

Tags: pcb-design, connector, bus, vibration, pci

I have to select between VME64 bus and PCI bus and one of the important decision metric is concerned with the connector types used in these buses. My application is in a vibrating environment. I cannot find any information or data for these buses if one of them will work in vibrating environment better than the other.

How can I do this evaluation? 
Will it be pure judgmental or should it be decided on some specification?

I will be connecting some cameras, displays and discrete I/Os on the bus. It's a 1-shot work for a custom application.

Comment: PCI or PCIe? Because PCIe is a serial bus with much lower pin count, and hence, companies like Molex offer ruggedized connectors and there's measurement buses (e.g. PXI Express) that work pretty reliably. Generally: While PCI / PCIe do have standard connectors, you're free to use your own connectors if you design all parts in the system. So, what kind of things will you connect via VME64 or PCI(e)?

Comment: I will be connecting some cameras, displays and discrete I/Os on the bus.

Comment: So, do these cameras, displays and IOs come with either a VMEbus or PCI interface already? Because honestly, in 2019 I'd have zero interest in designing a PCI device, when I could attach a camera using a ruggedized USB connector.

Comment: No idea about that as I only know my portion of the work.

Comment: I'm trying to understand that portion! Because, honestly, neither bus would be my choice for the kind of peripherals you've mentioned.

Comment: I just wonder whether after you've made that choice (say, you pick VME64), someone will start looking for *commercially available* VME64 motherboard components and VME64 cameras and VME64 Display interfaces, or whether someone will then start *designing* these components.

Comment: I sense XY problem.

Comment: That's two of us, @winny.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Its most probably the second of the two options that you mentioned. I am saying this because I know that its a 1-shot work for a custom application.

Comment: so, then use neither of the obsolete buses and pick a connector to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCI bus isn’t designed for rugged environment applications. Its mounting and edge-finger systems are generally not robust enough for high shock-and-vibe.

VME64 is better in this regard having been designed for industrial applications from the start. It has that robust DIN 41642 connector and supports hot-swap.

CompactPCI borrows similar rugged DIN connectors and mounting from VME. It may also be a good choice, it’s gaining popularity in certain markets like telecom.

That said, you have yet another choice to consider: PCIe/104, which is an evolution of the PCI/104 standard for industrial single-board computers. It uses a modular, stackable approach rather than a backplane like VME and CompactPCI.

Comment: I don't think the DIN connector has any special features to withstand vibration. It's more that VME systems often use nice robust (expensive) card cages with latches that hold the cards securely in the connectors.

Answer (score 2):

VMEBus is a dated design based on the 68000 peripheral bus, and has been slowly approaching obsolescence since the late 1990s. It's a poor choice for a new system; based on this alone, I'd choose PCI.

The vibrating environment is a red herring. The standard PCI edge connector might not be ideal for a vibrating environment, but there's plenty of other options, up to keeping the bus on-board and not dealing with any connectors at all.

Comment: I must admit I'm not an expert in automation buses, but shouldn't PCI be about as dead, being pretty dead in IT since the early 2000s?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not yet! While PCI Express is much more common for new hardware, PCI slots are still present on quite a few mainstream PC motherboards.

Comment: Given that even USB3.0 Gen 1 can achieve I/O rates that far outstrip PCI, it makes almost no sense to use it anymore unless you have some funky legacy peripheral to support.

Comment: @hacktastical Indeed! There are plenty of great modern alternatives. But the question didn't offer any of them as an option…

Comment: Interconnects are failure points. The lower the pin count the better. I’ve pushed for this many, many times with chip people, but they always balk at integrating the mixed signal block.